# User Creation Facebook Authentication, add non-facebook data on user submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, facebook

I have Facebook authentication working perfectly, however I have two different account types: `basic-user` and `member`. So I have two buttons where the user will choose `basic` or `member` and switch to the appropriate form.

**Question:**
What I want to figure out is how my facebook button could determine whether this is a `member` or `basic`. What could I add to the `member` portion of the login?

1st idea -My idea is making a hidden field with the `Facebook link_to omniauth facebook call and the submit button` for the the hidden field which will give `user_type`. to the user created.

One problem with this ^ is that the form submit with the hidden_field: `user_type` will go first before the facebook omniauth gets called. The registration path requires a password, so im not sure if this will work.

2nd idea - can i store information in the facebook button? could I put a second controller action for the button so that after facebook creates my user then the second action will take place which is the verification of the member.

or could i put a value in the facebook button to be passed to the same controller??

Heres what I have so far!

```rails
def self.from_omniauth(auth)

 anonymous_username = "NewUser#{User.last.id + 1}"
 generated_password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]

 user = User.where(:email => auth.info.email, :username => anonymous_username).first


 if user
  return user
else
  where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
    user.confirmed_at = Time.now
    user.fullname = auth.info.name
    user.provider = auth.provider
    user.uid = auth.uid
    user.username = anonymous_username
    user.email = auth.info.email
    user.password = generated_password
    if auth.info.image.present?
     avatar_url = process_uri(auth.info.image)
     user.avatar = URI.parse(avatar_url)
   end
 end

  end

end
```

[image: signup]

**Omniauth Callback_controller:**

```rails
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController


    def facebook
        @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

        if @user.persisted?
            sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
            set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
        else
            session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
            redirect_to new_user_registration_url

        end
    end

end
```

Facebook button + 1st idea `hidden_field`:

```rails
 <%= form_for(@user,  :url=> '/user/action', :method=> 'update', :html => {:id=>'facebook-form'} ) do |f| %>

  <%= link_to "Sign Up With Facebook", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook), :onclick => "$('#facebook-form').submit()", class:"btn btn-primary2" %>

  <% end %>
```

Comment: Store the user selection regarding basic/member in the session …?

Comment: im not too familiar with sessions. im using devise so where would i find the session? or is there a helper or something with devise?